# Android - ListView Items with specific IDs

Tags: android, database, listview

I'm developing a small application on android, and in an activity I need to display list of customers.
Actually I've done a query (by using Cursor object) which in result, it will output the ID (of customer) and CustomerName.

I need to display the CustomerName in ListView and in meantime, when user tap on a customer on the list, I could get the related ID.

can anyone help me with that ?

Comment: Store the ID in the tag property of the listview view and retrieve it in onClick http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642381/listview-and-hidden-id-how-it-is-possible

Comment: Have you tried anything? Where is your list adapter code?

Comment: An alternative is to override `getItemId()` in your adapter and return the data for the column that holds the unique id. If you're using the default `_id` column for that value, then you can skip this step. The id will then get passed in as parameter with every list item click: `onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)`. Unfortunately, this does only work if your unique id is a numeric value and not i.e. a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just follow these steps

1. Make a simple class having two variables like name and id class name: customer
2. now make a adapter class extending base adaptor override the getView method and set the text(name) of the customer
3. Handle clicks in the in listview onitemclick method

So heres a sample code

Pass the adapter an 
ArrayList<Customer>

So now your listview will have customer objects

On click you will get the customer object,use the parent.itematposition(position)
Cast the result of this method into customer alike this

Customer c=(Customer)parent.itematposition(position);

System.out.print(c.getId+c.getName());

public class Customer{
private Sting name;
private String id;

Provide setters and getters for both them so that they can be used above

}